# Бинарное дерево поиска

Tags: c++

Всем доброго время суток! Помогите, пожалуйста, дополнить программу, а именно нужны два метода поиск и удаление объектов из бинарного дерева поиска. Добавление кое-как осилил, а вот удаление и поиск не могу. Cуть такая, есть два класса, один класс - узел, второй класс дерево, вот внутри дерева надо сделать два метода, которые я сделать не могу.
Заранее всем спасибо

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
  private:
    int _value;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;

  public:
     Node(int value) {
        _value = value;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    } Node():_value(0), left(NULL), right(NULL) {
    }

    void SetLeft(Node * ptr) {
        left = ptr;
    }

    void SetRight(Node * ptr) {
        right = ptr;
    }

    void SetValue(int iValue) {
        _value = iValue;
    }

    int GetValue() {
        return _value;
    }

    Node *GetLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    Node *GetRight() {
        return right;
    }
};

class Tree {
  private:
    Node * head;

  public:

    Tree():head(NULL) {
    } Tree(int value) {
        Node *node = new Node(value);
        head = node;
    }

    Tree(Node * node) {
        head = node;
    }

    bool Add(Node * node, int value) {
        if (head == NULL) {
            Node *node = new Node(value);
            head = node;
            return true;
        }
        if (value >= node->GetValue()) {
            if (node->GetRight() != NULL)
                return Add(node->GetRight(), value);
            else {
                Node *newNode = new Node(value);
                node->SetRight(newNode);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if (node->GetLeft() != NULL)
                Add(node->GetLeft(), value);
            else {
                Node *newNode = new Node(value);
                node->SetLeft(newNode);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    bool Add(int value) {
        if (head == NULL) {
            Node *node = new Node(value);
            head = node;
            return true;
        }
        if (value >= head->GetValue()) {
            if (head->GetRight() != NULL)
                return Add(head->GetRight(), value);
            else {
                Node *newNode = new Node(value);
                head->SetRight(newNode);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if (head->GetLeft() != NULL)
                return Add(head->GetLeft(), value);
            else {
                Node *newNode = new Node(value);
                head->SetLeft(newNode);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    bool search(int ivalue) {
        if (ivalue == head->GetValue()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Ребят, неужели никто не может помочь?

Comment: А в чем проблема то? Обойти дерево рекурсивно и для удаления и для поиска можно. Я дак вообще не понимаю реализации бинарного дерева такой. (Хотя подозреваю по заданию обязательно так делать надо)

Comment: Ну вот в том и проблема, что я не вижу как "обойти дерево"...

Comment: Запускаешь в корне проверяешь значение, если значение найдено то заканчиваешь(если конечно значения уникальны, иначе дальше идешь), если нет вызываешь тот же метод для детей (если они не null).

Comment: Всмысле запускаешь в корне? посути у нас дерево - это объяекты.

Comment: Ну корень то есть (head)

Answer (score 1):

```
Node *Tree::RemoveNode(Node * root, int x)
{
    Node *t = new Node;
    if (root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (x == root->_value) {
        if (root->left == NULL) {
            t = root->right;
            delete root;
            return t;
        }
        t = root->left;
        while (t->right) {
            t = t->right;
        }
        t->right = root->right;
        return root->left;
    }
    if (x < root->_value)
        root->left = RemoveNode(root->left, x);
    else
        root->right = RemoveNode(root->right, x);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Это удаление?

Comment: Оно самое. В качестве параметров - указатель на вершину, и значение удаляемого элемента. Возвращает указатель на вершину дерева.

Comment: КУча ошибок выдало) ПОмоги плиз сделать гут код, это надо на курсач, а я вэбер, далёк от с++..

Comment: Какие ошибки хоть?

Comment: Дай мыло, я тебе скину исходник, там их миного очень )

Comment: Ответил на ящик

Comment: Спасибо, выслал тебе на мыло тоже)

Answer (score 0):

```
 bool Tree::search(int value, Node *node) {

    while (node != NULL){
    if (value == node->getValue()) {
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        if(value <= node->GetValue()) return search(value, node->GetLeft());
        else return search(value, node->GetRight());
    }
    }
    return false;
}

bool Tree::search(int value) {
    while (head != NULL){
    if (value == head->GetValue()) {
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        if(value <= head->GetValue()) return search(value, head->GetLeft());
        else return search(value, head->GetRight());
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```